# Reviews are discounted because others got there first

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

I think the review system is really good, except for two slight gripes, the first one is something I can simply accept and so I shall move onto the second one.

The system currently seems to let multiple people review the same question or answer at the same time, this can result in situations where you take the time to edit a post to help improve it, yet you do not count as performing the review as some one else has thrown a random vote on it and moved on.

If the system instead 'reserved' the post for you to review, it would all you take the time provide proper feed back, to take the time to work out what the post means and edit it, or to form a proper response to leave as a comment.

At the moment, the system seems to pressure people into quick shoddy reviews, if they had more time, it may not help counter that, but it will certainly help reward those people who wish to take the time to properly review posts.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149998/152859) might interest you. (Especially its second part :))

Comment: I almost posted a similar Q yesterday but then I found [this related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything). It's really frustrating when I invest time doing a proper review by making more substantial edits and never getting points on the review-o-meter.